# Azure AD B2C Custom policy Rest API Validation technical profile with response status code 200 /400/409 as output claims

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

As per the current requirement in forgot password custom policy before sending the Email verification code need to run a Rest API validation technical profile, which should allow continuing further success/error status and should add some precondition based on the response status code of this rest validation technical profile in action.

The solution I tried:-

To validate claims by using a validation technical profile in a custom policy, I define a Rest API validation technical profile. I set the `ContinueOnError` attribute to `true` to allow the policy to continue even if the REST API returns an error status code. I added a precondition in the next ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile to check the response status code of the REST API by using the `Precondition` element with the `Type` attribute set to `ClaimEquals` , the `Value` element set to the claim's name containing the response status code. If the response status code is 200, 400, or 409, I added an `Action` element with the value `SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile` to skip the validation technical profile.

Response of the Rest API:-

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "userMessage": "User don't have access on Addenda Quote, please contact administrator.",
    "status": 409,
    "isUserExist": false
}
```

Display Control:-

```
<DisplayControls>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailAddress" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailAddress" ControlClaimType="Email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="azureMfaSessionId" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-emailAddress" ContinueOnError = "true"/>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-ReadFromDB" ContinueOnError = "true">
              </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-SendCode">
              <Preconditions>
                  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                    <Value>objectId</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                  </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>status</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                  </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-VerifyCode" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>
```

Claim Type Definition:-

```
<ClaimType Id="status">
        <DisplayName>User access API status</DisplayName>
        <DataType>int</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
```

Technical profile:-

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ReadFromDB">
          <DisplayName>Validate User From DB</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https:........</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Header</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
          </InputClaims> 
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="status" PartnerClaimType = "status"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```